# Trying to understand how the guess game works in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Guess {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws java.io.IOException {

        char ch, ignore, answer = 'k';

        do {
            System.out.println("i'm thinking of a letter between a-z, can you guess it?");

            ch = (char) System.in.read();

            do { // <<question about this block, start**
                ignore = (char) System.in.read();
            } while (ignore != '\n'); // <<<end block in question here**

            if (ch == answer)
                System.out.println("***WINNER***");
            else {
                System.out.print("...sorry ");
                if (ch > answer)
                    System.out.println("toooo lowwww ");
                else {
                    System.out.println("tooooo highhh ");
                }
            }
        } while (answer != ch);

    }
}
```

how does this line make the program execute properly? I understand that it takes on any value the is not "\n" but if i delete this whole piece of code the program executes every single if, else statement. How is it allowing only the appropriate line to execute?

This is also my first post here, please let me know if I have done anything wrong or against the rules.

thank you.

Comment: Dude, this is a very very very simple program. You should be able to understand it if you try a little bit more and if you have the basics of programming, like how a `if` or a `while` loop work, and I am not downvoting, because I understand that at the beginning things might seem frustrating, mostly when you don't have time.

Comment: why not adding a breakpoint start debugging  and watching the values ? ..  logic is easy .. just read first char and save it after that ignore all chars that pressed while ignore not equal .. ;)

Comment: Learn about debugging you will like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    ignore = (char) System.in.read();
} while (ignore != '\n');
```

This code will continue to read characters from standard input until it reads a newline.  This is to discard all additional characters until the game prompts the user for a character again.

You could have entered `abc` the first time. Without that code, if you got the answer wrong, the game would prompt you for another letter, but then it would read `b` you entered the first time.

Comment: thanks for the response, i don't think i'm presenting the question clearly. I understand what that specific line does for the program, but when i remove the block of code, and run the program,  the game works but it repeats the corresponding text exactly 3 times. essentially i'm trying to understand how the line buffering works with input. the do-while loop repeats it exactly 3 times before ceasing and waiting for a new console input. Why exactly is it doing that?

Comment: Shouldn't it keep looping forever?